# What Firewall Port is required for snap package management?

Tags: snap, firewall, ubuntu-core, ufw

I'm firewalling an ***Ubuntu Core 16.04*** host: What port does ***snap package management*** require to be opened?

I spent ages Googling this: Snapcraft's docs don't detail the port nor did any other forums.  Couldn't use `tcpdump` to derive the required port as `snap find tcpdump` gave no joy.

In the end, I had to packetsniff on the router.  I'll provide the answer to hopefully save others firewalling Ubuntu Core hosts the same exercise in frustration...

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/docs/network-requirements has more recent info about required network connectivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to allowing DNS of course, Ubuntu Core requires ***TCP/443*** connectivity for snap package management to check for updates & install packages. The Ubuntu Core host on 192.168.1.26 is using a port from the Dynamic/Private port range, ***TCP/35234***

[image: Packet Sniff Capture]

Doing a host lookup of `host 91.189.92.20` reports the remote IP as Snapcraft's:

```
20.92.189.91.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer api.snapcraft.io.
```

Anyhoo, hope this saves others some time-

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and had to add the following domains to be able to establish http(s) connections:

```
api.snapcraft.io 
public.apps.ubuntu.com 
snapcraft.io 
fastly.cdn.snapcraft.io
```

At least, it was working after adding the fourth one.